# What is the difference between partialSubmit and autoSubmit in JSF?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I guess I knew the difference, but right now I find myself confused. :P

Both of them seem to be do the same thing, except that `partialSubmit` is used on submit buttons to submit the form using AJAX and `autoSubmit` is used on editable components, which submits only its own contents. Am I right in saying this?

Comment: Please note that "partialSubmit" term is specific to ICEFaces component library, not to standard JSF. I added the ICEFaces tag.

Comment: Oh! Anyway I was speaking in context of ADF.

Comment: ADF? That should be explicitly mentioned then :) Note that community support for ADF is here pretty low. I won't expect quick and accurate ADF-specific answers.

Comment: Yes. That's why I don't ask ADF question here, but I had assumes that this was JSF stuff.

Comment: No, this is not standard JSF. Standard JSF is whatever you have in `javax.faces.*` package and in `http://java.sun.com/jsf/*` tags/components. Not mentioning about any 3rd party component library you're using would only lead to confusion and/or bad/incomplete answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both AJAX enabled calls occurring from custom properties of custom JSF components.  The `autoSubmit` essentially asynchronously postsback content specific to the component for keeping the server side managed bean values current with the content within the component on the client side.

A `partialSubmit` is another asynchronous AJAX call that will serve to immediately postback a component value on some kind of component event, like losing focus on an ICEFaces inputText component for example.

The interesting thing to note is that the entire ViewState is posted back on each type of asynchronous submit, so if the values of other components HAD changed on the page before the submit, the bound server side managed bean properties will have their values refreshed as well, even though the client side components MAY not be refreshed to reflect any server side data changes that may have occurred.

In fact, the entire JSF server side lifecycle occurs on each postback, read the following article on implementing a debug PhaseListener that allows you to see what Phases are occurring after each asynchronous submit operation occurs.

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html

Comment: the only difference I see between `autoSubmit` and `partialSubmit` is the word 'immediate'. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @AppleGrew, Don't read too much into my exact words, what I am basically trying to say is that they both are almost exactly the same.  They are ICEFaces custom properties for different ICEFaces components, but behind the scenes they basically do exactly the same thing.  The only difference between the two is exactly when the postback occurs.

Comment: NVM, my last comment, it is not correct because I thought you were talking about ICEfaces.  Try switching to a technology that has a little more of a community around it :)

Comment: No problem. I guess ADF and ICE's behavior should be similar for such simple cases. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer isn't 100% correct for ADF. The `partialTriggers` attribute is involved in the lifecycle.

From [Enabling Partial Page Rendering Declaratively](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/b31973/af_ppr.htm#BABHBJFH%20Enabling%20Partial%20Page%20Rendering%20Declaratively)

> The `autoSubmit` attribute on an input component and the `partialSubmit`
>   attribute on a command component are not the same thing. When
>   `partialSubmit` is set to true, then only the components that have
>   values for their `partialTriggers` attribute will be processed through
>   the lifecycle. The `autoSubmit` attribute is used by input and select
>   components to tell the framework to automatically do a form submit
>   whenever the value changes. However, when a form is submitted and the
>   `autoSubmit` attribute is set to true, a valueChangeEvent event is
>   invoked, and the lifecycle runs only on the components marked as root
>   components for that event, and their children. For more information,
>   see Section 4.4, "[Using the Optimized Lifecycle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/b31973/af_lifecycle.htm#CIAHCFJF%20Using%20the%20Optimized%20Lifecycle)".